# How to extend date in PHP?

Tags: php

I have developed a subscription website. I am facing php date extend problem.

Please read my message-

Suppose today i have subscribe a package. Package duration 1 month. I mean 2014-05-08 to  2014-06-07

After two days i will again subscribe this same package. now the Package duration will extend 2014-06-07 to 2014-07-07

In my PHP code i am getting current date to +1 month but how to get after 1 month to next one month?

I have used this code:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+$getSubscription['Subscription']['duration'], date("d"), date("Y")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) to achieve this.

Check this out:

```
<?php

// current subscription expiry date
$day = '2014-06-07';

// add 30 days to the date above
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . " +30 days"));

// debug
echo $new_date;
```

Outputs: `2014-07-07`

P.s. are you saving the newly calculated date into db or something and then using it on the next calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Or use the DateTime object :

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2014-06-07');
$date_end = clone $date;
$date_end->add(new DateInterval('P1M');

echo $date_end->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd save yourself a lot of hassle by using DateTime objects instead of messing around with date() and mktime(). In order to get today, simply:

```
$subscriptionDate = new DateTime(); // 2014-05-08
```

Then you can use the DateInterval class to add additional months, so if it's a monthly subscription, simply:

```
$subscriptionPeriod = new DateInterval('P1M');
$subscriptionDate->add($subscriptionPeriod);
```

Now, `$subscriptionDate` will be at 2014-06-08. You can keep adding as many months as you want and save it to your database, in the format you want, like:

```
$subscriptionDate->format('Y-m-d'); // 2014-06-08
$subscriptionDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // incl. time, e.g. 2014-06-08 12:02:45
```

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) for more examples.